# Save SharePreference string to a ListView

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I have two activities. Let's say "A" and "B", Activity "A" has a button called "Get" which generates a new string after each click and displays them one at a time.  And the activity "A" also has a button "send" which will send the generated strings to another activity "B". When the activity "B" receives the data, it has to populate the data into a ListView.

Here's the simple step by step machine steps:

```
In Activity "A"
1 - Generate 1 string by pressing the generate button
2 - text will be displayed in textView
3 - "send" button will send the text from textView to another activity "B" ( I'm using sharedPreference)

In Activity "B"
4 - receive the data sent by Activity "A" ( I'm using sharedPreference)
5 - populate string into a listview
6 - go to step 1 again.
```

My trouble is that whenever I click the send button, it will send the string to Activity "B" but when I do the same task again, it will only populate the last generated string. In other words, my code only populates one string.

I have tried following code so far, any help would be appreciated.

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {


        switch(view.getId()) {
            case R.id.generateButton:
                generateString();
                break;

            case R.id.send:

                //displayText is a textView
                String text = displayText.getText().toString(); 

                // data sharing using sharedPref
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("lado", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                editor.putString("mug",text);
                editor.apply();
                break;


        }

---------
```

Activity B

```
ListView textList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("lado", MODE_PRIVATE);
        final String text = prefs.getString("mug", "No name defined");

       String[] list = new String[]{name};


        // Create a List from String Array elements
        final List<String> fav_list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(list));



        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1,list);

        // Assign adapter to ListView
        textList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Please show me your full code and expain what you want :)

Comment: Using same key in shared preference will overwrite your previous value so keep one list or array to store group of values in shared preferences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add below model:

**Dictionary.java**

```
class Dictionary implements Serializable {
    private List<Words> wordsList = new ArrayList<>();


    List<Words> getWordsList() {
        return wordsList;
    }

    void setWordsList(List<Words> wordsList) {
        this.wordsList = wordsList;
    }
}
```

**Words.java**

```
public class Words implements Serializable {

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

**Activity A**

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {


        switch(view.getId()) {
            case R.id.generateButton:
                generateString();
                break;

            case R.id.send:

                //displayText is a textView
                String text = generateButton.getText().toString(); 

               SharedPreferences pref = this.getSharedPreferences("lado", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);



                Words words = new Words();
                words.setName(text);
                List<Words> wordsList = new ArrayList<>();

                Gson gson = new Gson();
                Dictionary dictionary = gson.fromJson(pref.getString("word", ""), Dictionary.class);
                if (dictionary != null && dictionary.getWordsList() != null) {
                    wordsList.addAll(dictionary.getWordsList());
                    dictionary.setWordsList(wordsList);
                    wordsList.add(words);
                } else {
                    dictionary = new Dictionary();
                    wordsList.add(words);
                    dictionary.setWordsList(wordsList);
                }
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
                editor.putString("word", new Gson().toJson(dictionary));
                editor.commit();

                break;


        }
```

**Activity B**

```
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("lado", MODE_PRIVATE);

 List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
Gson gson = new Gson();
Dictionary dictionary = gson.fromJson(pref.getString("word", ""), Dictionary.class);
if (dictionary != null)
    for (Words words : dictionary.getWordsList()) {
        list.add(words.getName());
    }
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, list);

// Assign adapter to ListView
textList.setAdapter(adapter);

//**Remove when click on item**
textList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Dictionary dictionary = gson.fromJson(pref.getString("word", ""), Dictionary.class);
        for (Words words :
                dictionary.getWordsList()) {
            if (words.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(list.get(i))) {
                dictionary.getWordsList().remove(words);
                list.remove(i);
                break;
            }
        }
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putString("word", new Gson().toJson(dictionary));
        editor.commit();

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I think you misunderstood but, I wanted to send the string data from Activity "A" to "B" and then populate the string into a ListView in the Activity B. Remember that there will be only one generated String at a time in Activity "A". That one string should be populated into Activity "B" by pressing the "send" button one by one

Comment: please look at my updated question, thank you very much!! :)

Comment: I was playing with the code, and I was wondering how could I approach if I want to delete the listview completely. I tried "adapter.remove()" but it only wipes the view, when I re-open the app, the data will show up. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use shared preferences for this, but rather I would just pass the list as an extra in an intent from the A activity.  Something like this:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("hello");
list.add("good");
list.add("bye");
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(list);
Intent goToNextActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), YourActivity.class);
goToNextActivity.putExtra("words", array.toString());
startActivity(goToNextActivity);
```

Then in the B activity you can access this data:

```
String words = getIntent().getStringExtra("words");
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(words);
```

Comment: Sorry, I think you misunderstood but, I wanted to send the string data from Activity "A" to "B"  and then populate the string into a ListView in the Activity B.  Remember that there will be only one generated String at a time in Activity "A". That one string should be populated into Activity "B" by pressing the "send" button one by one.

Comment: please look at my updated question, thank you very much!! :)

Comment: @user7062312b Your requirment makes no sense to me.  Activity B doesn't "know" what has been sent to it until it actually loads.  At that point, it wakes up and conceptually sees a bunch of strings.  Whether or not they came in one by one is irrelevant (and if not, then you should explain why not).

Answer (score 0):

you can use the below solution

```
    @Override
public void onClick(View view) {


    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.generateButton:
            //declare a public list
            list.add(generateString());
            break;

        case R.id.send:

            //displayText is a textView
            JSONArray data=new JSONArray(list);

            // data sharing using sharedPref
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("lado", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            editor.putString("mug",data.toString());
            editor.apply();
            break;


    }
```

Activity B

```
    ListView textList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    // receiving data from MapsActivity
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("lado", MODE_PRIVATE);
    final String text = prefs.getString("mug", "No name defined");

    JSONArray data=new JSONArray(text);


    // Create a List from String Array elements
    final List<String> fav_list = new ArrayList<>();


     if (data != null) { 
      for (int i=0;i<data.length();i++){ 
         fav_list.add(data.getString(i));
      } 
     } 



    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1,fav_list );

    // Assign adapter to ListView
    textList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: please look at my updated question, thank you very much!! :)