# How to store an ArrayList in SharedPreferences?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, sharedpreferences, hashset

I have a sorted `ArrayList` of contacts. I want to store the list in `SharedPreference`. I have tried the below code:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = app_preference.edit();
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
set.addAll(contact_names_list);
editor.putStringSet("CONTACT_LIST", set);
editor.apply();
```

The problem is, when I retrieve this from `HashSet` I got an unsorted list. Is there any other way to store `ArrayList` other than `Hashset`?

Comment: are you saying `set ` does not have ordered value ?

Comment: You can find your answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47973805/save-sharepreference-string-to-a-listview

Comment: Why don't you just use a database? It will make things much easier

Comment: Shared preferences store values in xml format, database is a better option

Comment: `... I got an unsorted list.` and what's the problem in sorting it once it's been retrieved and before presenting it to the user?

Comment: @NoiseGenerator he wants to retain the insertion order

Comment: @WilliMentzel Which is probably an ordered list... so, what changes, to sort it *after*?

Comment: @NoiseGenerator how can it be an ordered list? it's a HashSet in his case. how can he know the insertion order after retrieval? the information is lost then. pls, see my answer. maybe I am not thinking straight :D

Comment: @WilliMentzel The insertion order is probably an alphabetical or by number or "by any field" order. He knows how the list should be sorted. And can use the same field to re-order the list once retrieved.

Comment: @NoiseGenerator you don't know that. that's your guess. in would see it in a more generic way. I have a sorted list and I want to keep that sorting no matter what logic it follows.

Comment: you can check this .... it will help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/15011927/6559031

Comment: @WilliMentzel True, I don't know that. I suppose the developer does know the logic s/he uses across the program. I just made a *reasonable* supposition.

Comment: @Noise Generator ,@WilliMentzel , In my app i have generated all the contacts in sorted order   "ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME+" ASC"", and there is an option to delete contacts from the sorted list , and i am saving the contacts list in to SharedPreference  when activity onStop called , and i want to retrive the same list on next app launch .So i can not reorder the list .Hope you understood

Comment: And **why** can't you reorder the list on the name field *on retrieval*?

Comment: @Gibs I you delete items from an ordered list the resulting list is still ordered. so, why not sorting it after retrieval (what Noise Generator says)?

Comment: Ok i can make it clear , i have a sorted list of contact names and i have a separate list of numbers of each contact.Total two lists, i want to save both lists in  preference, when the user deletes a name from the app ,i want to delete the corresponding number  from numbersList ,when i use hashset ,this number list also becomes orderless , so after retrivel i can reorder the name list , but what to do with number list ?

Comment: hope you understood

Comment: hashset changes the order of number list too ,so i can't reorder it based on corresponding contact list.

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve the values

```
Set<String> set = myScores.getStringSet("CONTACT_LIST", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static Prefs singleton = null;

public static Prefs with(Context context) {
        if (singleton == null) {
            singleton = new Builder(context).build();
        }
        return singleton;
    }
```

Do it this way-:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = app_preference.edit();
        Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
        set.addAll(contact_names_list);
        editor.putStringSet("CONTACT_LIST", set);
        editor.apply();

or

Prefs.with(getAppContext()).putStringSet("CONTACT_LIST", set);
```

Retrive the values by using this code-:

```
Set<String> existindData = Prefs.with(getAppContext()).getStringSet("CONTACT_LIST", null);
```

Comment: Its a class that i have made for prefs.let me edit it

Answer (score 0):

Since `putStringSet` accepts any class which implements the `Set` interface
you can use a `LinkedHashSet` which retains the order of insertion.

Documentaion of [LinkedHashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html):

> This implementation differs from HashSet in that it maintains a
>   doubly-linked list running through all of its entries. This linked
>   list defines the iteration ordering, which is the order in which
>   elements were inserted into the set (insertion-order).

`HashSet` does not retain order of insertion, which is the problem here.

```
// ...

Set<String> set = new LinkedHashSet<String>();

// insert from ArrayList
set.addAll(contact_names_list);

// or single elements
set.add("Homer");
set.add("Marge");

editor.putStringSet("CONTACT_LIST", set);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response , i have tried with LinkedHashSet but still i am getting unsorted list.

Answer (score 0):

Save **array** in **SharedPreferences** :

```
 SharedPreferences shdPre=getSharedPreferences("MainActivity",MODE_PRIVATE);
    shdPre.edit().putInt("Size",myarray.size());
    while(i<myarray.size())
    {
shdPre.edit().remove("value"+i).commit();
shdPre.edit().putString("value"+i,myarray.get(i)).commit();
i++;
}
```

---

Load  **array** from **SharedPreferences**

```
SharedPreferences shdPre=getSharedPreferences("MainActivity",MODE_PRIVATE);
 myarray =new ArrayList();
 Int msize=shdPre.getInt("Size",null);
 while(i<msize)
{
myarray.add(shdPre.getString("value" + i, null);
i++;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As the Android documentation explains https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences.html?hl=en the Share Preferences is a way to save Key-Value data. Given that that behind scenes that dictionary can be save in almost a random order you can't retrieve something in order. However I can recommend a couple of solutions:

1. **The easy not good performance one:** Add as part of the value the index, therefore you can create an array with the size of the Hashset and then iterate the Hashset and add every element in the array that you created. O(N) temporal complexity plus the one involved in the reading process of the file.
2. **Saved the data in a local SQLite database:** This solution is more flexible in future terms (you can add new contacts). https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite.html Usually you create your own SQLite database that you put in assets and then you just import it. You can create queries to bring them in the order that you want (maybe create a column for that).

   ```
   InputStream myInput = context.getAssets( ).open( "test.db" );

   // Path to the just created empty db
   String outFileName = "/data/YOUR_APP/test.db";

   // Open the empty db as the output stream
   OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream( outFileName );

   // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
   byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
   int length;
   while( ( length = myInput.read( buffer ) ) > 0 )
   {
       myOutput.write( buffer, 0, length );
   }
   // Close the streams
   myOutput.flush( );
   myOutput.close( );
   myInput.close( );
   ```
3. **Simple not scalable option:** In the values `folder` you can always create a `strings.xml` file where you can put that data as a `string-array`. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html?hl=en

   `<string-array name="types">
           <item>A</item>
           <item>B and users</item>
           <item>C</item>
           <item>D</item>
           <item>E</item>
       </string-array>`

If you need something more structured I have done stuff like this (saved as JSON).

```
<string-array name="quality_attributes">
        <item>{id:1,name:Performance,sub:[{id:2,name:Scalability},{id:3,name:Response_Time}]}</item>
        <item>{id:4,name:Security,sub:[{id:5,name:Availability,sub:[{id:6,name:Reliability},{id:7,name:Recovery}]},{id:8,name:Privacy}]}</item>
        <item>{id:9,name:Interoperability}</item>
        <item>{id:10,name:Maintainability}</item>
        <item>{id:12,name:Testability}</item>
        <item>{id:13,name:Usability,sub:[{id:14,name:Findability},{id:15,name:Correctness}]}</item>
    </string-array>
```

And in my code:

```
String[] elementsArray = getResources().getStringArray(
                R.array.quality_attributes);

        for (int i = 0; i < attributesArray.length; i++) {
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            MyJsonObject obj = gson.fromJson(elementsArray[i],
                    MyJsonObject.class);
           // Do something
        }
```

In general terms if you want something that needs to be change, the second options is the best one. If you are looking for something simple, the third option is good enough.

Answer (score -2):

We can use Java 8 sorting way for sorting the collections .
    `Set<String> s = new HashSet<String>();
    s.add("Kunal");
    s.add("Bhism");
    s.add("Work");
    s.add("Abdgg");
    s.add("Psss");
    s.add("Work");
    List<Object> l = s.stream().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(l);`
Try this above code , you will get the sorted HashSet now.